# MySQL - Entries with duplicate unique fields

Tags: mysql, database, unique

I've got two entires here in a MySQL database. 
 
Entries:

[image: entries]

As you can see these have the exact same slug.
But if we look at the structure.

Structure:

[image: structure]

It has the unique constraint. This has been there since the table was created.
Nothing has been changed as well.
I didn't think this was possible. Am I missing something?

EDIT - Testing for whitespace
I actually had another instance this happened here:
[Instance 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKSQr.png)
Here is the output of `select distinct slug from listing`

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyiOL.png)

Comment: what is output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name` ?

Comment: Can we see the ouput of HEX(slug)

Comment: @Strawberry look at the comments on the answer below, we tested for distinctness

Comment: I still think SHOW CREATE TABLE might be useful

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation I can think of is that those two values in the `slug` column actually do differ from whitespace.  Assuming that leading/trailing whitespace is the culprit, the following query should confirm that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT slug
FROM yourTable;
```

If this shows *two* records with `comment-3`, then the two `slug` values are not the same.  Now trying trimming both records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM slug) slug
FROM yourTable;
```

If my conjecture be correct, then you should see just a single value now.

Comment: It only shows one record with it, i'll update my post with this information

Comment: What does "It" refer to here?  My first query or my second query?

Comment: Sorry, first query!

Comment: What you are describing is not possible.  If you have a unique constraint on `slug`, then two records _can't_ have the same value.

Comment: I have everything in front of me, is there anything else I can show you?